# Updating a feed fails: Signer address does not match the update request

Tags: swarm

This is what I run (`0x65686c6c0a` is "hello" in hex)

```
swarm --verbosity 2 --bzzaccount `cat Alice` --passsword Pass &
swarm --bzzaccount `<Alice` --password Pass feed create --name neverchanges > FeedHash
swarm --bzzaccount `<Alice` --password Pass feed update --manifest `cat FeedHash` 0x65686c6c0a
```

I'd expect swarm to update the feed, but I get `Fatal: Signer address does not match the update request` instead.

Comment: won't `swarm --bzzaccount \`<Alice\` feed create --name neverchanges > FeedHash` fail when you don't give a password? maybe add `< <(echo -n <password>)` at the end or use `--password <passwordfile>`?

Comment: I called every line with `--password Pass`, I just didn't want too long lines here. Now I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake. I accidentally changed the value of FeedHash before running the last command.